# asp-validation-for tag helper is not working for server side validation errors

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

**CustomerEntryModel**

```
    [Required]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
```

**CustomerController.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Get")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        CustomerEntryModel model = new CustomerEntryModel();
        return View("CustomerEntry", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Update")]
    public ActionResult Update([FromForm]CustomerEntryModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("CustomerEntry", model);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**CustomerEntry.cshtml**

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
<form asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Update" method="post">
    <input type="text" asp-for="FirstName" />
    <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I do not include the jQuery validation libraries, so the validation occurs on the server side. Now, when I submit the page with first name empty, the update action gets executed and I receive back the same view, but without any error.

Instead of `<span asp-validation-for="FirstName" />` tag helper, if I use the html helper `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)` I get the required error for first name.

As per my understanding `TagHelper` extends the behavior of traditional `HtmlHelper` to provide HTML friendly development experience. That means, something that works with `HtmlHelper` has to work with it's `TagHelper` counterpart.

After the `ModelState.IsValid` call, I CAN see `Controller.ModelState` (instance of `ModelStateDictionary`), having the error for `FirstName` property. However, the `TagHelper` isn't able to bind it.

You can find the MVC6 validation tag helpers detail here,

http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/14/mvc6-validation-tag-helpers-deep-dive.aspx

Comment: This is a registered issue in the framework https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4475

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I suggest try changing this:

```
<span asp-validation-for="FirstName" />
```

like this:

```
<span asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
```

maybe it will make a difference

Comment: I am having the same problem as the OP and this does not work.

Comment: Yes, surprisingly the self-closing tag causes the problem.

Comment: best answer of the day ;)

Comment: It is amazing that this fixed it for me. What's the difference?

Comment: The issue still exists even in 2024, with asp.net core 8.